# Add or Update to sharepoint with .net code

Tags: development, web-services

Is there any ready-made code (c#, .net) to add/update documents in SP Library? I am sure using web services. Can anyone please suggest? Also, is there a way to get the Doc ID back after an item has been added to the SP.

Comment: Getting the ID of a newly uploaded document is a separate question, so open a new one with just that, and edit out that question from this one.

Comment: @JamesLove: Thank you sir. About to post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First result in Google for ["SharePoint add document using web services"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sharepiont%20add%20document%20using%20web%20services) :-

[Codeproject - Uploading files to the SharePoint Document Library and updating any metadata columns](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/File_Shunter.aspx)